Control selection narrowing menu when hitting overlapping VOs in AnalyticMap SAP Ui5
This is the extract from the library that control the event when I click on overlapping Areas:
if (event.hitTests.length > 1) 
{
    scene.showHitMenu(event, event.hitTests); // show menu to narrow selection to one vo
    delete event.hitTests; //has to be deleted to avoid collecting hits information again
    event.preventDefault();
    return true;
}

This is the XML where the MAPContainer is defined:
<vk:MapContainer id="mapC" autoAdjustHeight="true" width="90%" >
    <vk:content>
        <vk:ContainerContent title="Analytic Map">
            <vk:content>
                <vbm:AnalyticMap id="HDR" width="100%" xmlns:l="sap.ui.layout" height="80%" initialPosition="6.56;13.28;0" initialZoom="7"
                 regionContextMenu="onRegionContextMenu" scaleVisible="true" legendVisible="true" click="myClick" 
                    select="onSelect" centerChanged="onCenterChanged" zoomChanged="onZoomChanged">
                    <vbm:resources>
                        <vbm:Resource name="ErrorNotComment" src="images/spots/createdNotComment_Dalt.png"/>
                        <vbm:Resource name="ErrorComment" src="images/spots/createdComment_Dalt.png"/>
                        <vbm:Resource name="WarningNotComment" src="images/spots/repairedNotComment_Dalt.png"/>
                        <vbm:Resource name="WarningComment" src="images/spots/repairedComment_Dalt.png"/>
                        <vbm:Resource name="SuccessNotComment" src="images/spots/verifiedNotComment_Dalt.png"/>
                        <vbm:Resource name="SuccessComment" src="images/spots/verifiedComment_Dalt.png"/>
                        <vbm:Resource name="InactiveNotComment_0_Dalt" src="images/spots/inactiveNotComment_0_Dalt.png"/>
                        <vbm:Resource name="InactiveComment_0_Dalt" src="images/spots/inactiveComment_0_Dalt.png"/>
                        <vbm:Resource name="AssistedNotComment_0_Dalt" src="images/spots/assistedNotComment_0_Dalt.png"/>
                        <vbm:Resource name="AssistedComment_0_Dalt" src="images/spots/assistedComment_0_Dalt.png"/>
                        <vbm:Resource name="InactiveNotComment_1_Dalt" src="images/spots/inactiveNotComment_1_Dalt.png"/>
                        <vbm:Resource name="InactiveComment_1_Dalt" src="images/spots/inactiveComment_1_Dalt.png"/>
                        <vbm:Resource name="InactiveNotComment_2_Dalt" src="images/spots/inactiveNotComment_2_Dalt.png"/>
                        <vbm:Resource name="InactiveComment_2_Dalt" src="images/spots/inactiveComment_2_Dalt.png"/>
                    
                        
                    </vbm:resources>
                    <vbm:vos>

                        <vbm:Routes id="Routes" items="{/Routes}">
                            <vbm:Route position="{position}" color="{color}" start="{start}" end="{end}" tooltip="{defectTypeDesc} {comment}"
                     labelText="{text}" labelBgColor="RGB(0;0;0)" linewidth="{linewidth}" lineDash="{lineDash}"/>
                        </vbm:Routes>
                 
                        <vbm:Areas id="Areas" items="{/Areas}" contextMenu="onContextMenuItem" >
                            <vbm:Area id="Area" contextMenu="changeFixOmega" tooltip="{defectTypeDesc} {comment}" color="{color}" colorBorder="{border}"
                                position="{polygon}" labelArrow="false" labelBgColor="{labelColor}" labelBorderColor="{labelColor}" labelPos="0" 
                     labelText="{text}"/>
                        </vbm:Areas>            
                   
                
                      <vbm:Areas id="AreasLocked" items="{/AreasLocked}" contextMenu="onContextMenuItem">
                        <vbm:Area id="AreaLocked" click="onClickAreaLocked" contextMenu="onContextMenuArea" position="{polygon}" color="{color}" colorBorder="{border}"/>
                        </vbm:Areas>    
                
                        <vbm:Spots id="Spots" items="{/Spots}">
                            <vbm:Spot position="{position}" tooltip="{defectTypeDesc}{comment}" contentOffset="0;2" hotDeltaColor="{color}" text="{text}" click="onControlClicked"
                                    contentColor="{path: 'comment', formatter: 'util.my.Formatter.spotContentFont' }"  image="{ parts : [ 'type', 'comment'], formatter: 'util.my.Formatter.spotImage' }"/>
                        </vbm:Spots>
                                    
                                     

                    </vbm:vos>
                </vbm:AnalyticMap>
            </vk:content>
        </vk:ContainerContent>
    </vk:content>
</vk:MapContainer>

There is a function when happens a click --> myClick, but in the case there is a overlapping, instead of enter myClick function it automatically generates a Popup menu to select the object among the possible ones.
I need to know if is is possible to control that Popup, or disactivate it
